# How can i manage too many requests in Angular

Tags: angular, spring, http, post

I have a problem with Angular http calls.
My app is making http post requests in a for loop, sequentially.
Its about nearly 2000 calls.
I get "err_insufficient_resources" error in client side chrome a while later.
How can i group requests and make them wait each others to finish.
And then send new groups of requests.
Can i do this in that way ? Or do you have another idea to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: That is an example of bad design, you need to be thinking better about how you handle requests on the backend

Comment: There are many options to do this.   Promise-based Queues (or async/await queues, whichever) is one approach that comes to mind.   Maybe provide an example of how these calls are being executed (summarize of course) to help diagnose what your issue is.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the requests are being made, so that a solution can be proposed.

Answer (score 0):

What are you requesting from the server 2000 times in a row? That seems like an underlying problem to me.  As Kurt said, we would need to know how and why those requests are being made in order to offer a solution.